# Initialize derived class?

Tags: c++, derived-class

In header:

```
class foo : public ISceneNode
{
public:
   foo(){}

   void setAge(int a) { age = a; }

   int getAge(){ return age; }

private:
   int age;
}
```

In source:

```
foo::foo()
:ISceneNode(0,0)
{
    age = 5;
}
```

For example, I have this class with a member variable. The member variable is 5.
In main:

```
foo* node = (foo*)smgr->addCubeSceneNode(2);
int age = node->getAge();
```

It works, however the problem is, program is now unaware of the member variable, since I have not created foo() with new. So, getAge() method returns nothing!

My question is, how do I initialize the member variable?

Thank you.

Comment: What does `smgr->addCubeSceneNode(2)` do, and why do you treat the result as a `foo*`, when it doesn't point to a real `foo`?

Comment: The question makes no sense to me.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. You're asking how to do something which probably should never be done. Please back up and ask a new question about whether `(foo*)smgr->addCubeSceneNode(2);` is the right thing to do, providing its context.

Comment: I would second @Potatoswatter - please post some surrounding code and the actual error/issue you are getting. Are you simply doing a memory allocation (`malloc`) without a `new`? I would prefer not to second-guess your problem. :)

Comment: cubeSceneNode is an another derived class, which is IMeshSceneNode, of ISceneNode.

Comment: That's an explanation that explains nothing.

Comment: You need to study a book. There are free books on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `age` is not marked `public`. This is the reason you cannot access it from outside the class. Creating an object with `new` has nothing to do with your problem.

```
class foo : public ISceneNode
{
   foo(){}
public:
   int age;
};
```

Unrelated note: You might want to make `foo()` public too.

Comment: Or use `struct` instead of class… just a good default rule for interfaces where access hasn't yet been thought-out. However, there seem to be deeper issues here.

Comment: Sorry, actually those are public, I am typing from phone, thats why getting a little bit confused. I have a public method, getAge().

Comment: @Potatoswatter Agree about the code smell. Something's not quite right here.

Comment: Personally I think the problem is the missing semicolon, since the code that doesn't compile can't possibly do what it's intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

frequently member variables of class are declared as private variables, because we can prevent unprotected accesses.

```
class foo: public ISceneNode
{
    foo(){}
    int age;
};
```

This snipet creates a class named foo(usually, we capitalize class name, such as Foo) which derives from ISceneNode. It is the relationship of "is-a".

keyword **class** indicates the default access rule is private while keyword **strcut** means public.

non-static Member variables are initialized through constructors. As stated before, your constructor is private, you can not access it through an object.

```
foo obj; // not allowed
```

if you add "public:"

```
class foo: public ISceneNode
{
int age;
public:
    foo(){age = 5;}
};

foo obj; // ok, age now equals 5;
```

But you also have to deal with the initialization of base class. Above code require the base class has a default constructor.

Comment: Yes, the base class has default construction and that class is a part of the irrlicht library. I need to re-edit my post a little.